# RouteConfig is not declared Error Message in VS2012

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio, url-routing

I am trying out [FriendlyUrls](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx) in VS2012. I am using the readme and Hanselman's post as a guide. i added the following to Application Start but VS tells me RouteConfig is not declared.

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
```

I have googled but have not found an answer. I have imported system.web.routing. 
How do I correct this error message

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved it. The FriendlyUrls Package when installed from the package manager console creates a RouteConfig.cs file in App_Start even if the project is a VBNet project. So just create the equiavlent vbnet file and the erro will go away.

Comment: In my case the FriendlyUrls package created both RouteConfig.vb and RouteConfig.cs files in App_Start, so I needed to delete RouteConfig.cs.  It also created both BundleConfig.vb and BundleConfig.cs, so I deleted the cs file in this case.